# SQLite Database Reopen in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I do not see any methods in `SQLiteDatabase` class and `SQLiteDatabaseOpener` Therefore I got this error:

```
AndroidRuntime(806): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to acquire a reference on a close SQLiteClosable
```

What would be a good way of designing it so that I can use the database throughout say a certain class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is right here
[Exception: attempt to acquire a reference on a close SQLiteClosable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483629/exception-attempt-to-acquire-a-reference-on-a-close-sqliteclosable)

This one drove me insane for the longest time. The solution I have found is fairly simple: don't keep references to SQLiteDatabase objects. Instead, use a SQLiteOpenHelper and call getWritableDatabase() every time you need one. From the docs:

> public synchronized SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase()
>
> Create and/or open a database that will be used for reading and
>   writing. Once opened successfully, the database is cached, so you can
>   call this method every time you need to write to the database.
>
> The answer was right there the whole time.